# How to get RawUrl in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rawurl

Is there any way to get `RawUrl` before rewrite in IIS? I have a rewrite rule in `web.config` which rewrites a url if match found. Now I want to get RawUrl.

My Raw url is

```
https://example.com/drapes-equipment-covers/72586-00034-00/
```

which I rewrite to

```
https://example.com/product/?x=drapes-equipment-covers&y=72586-00034-00
```

But RawTarget returns

```
https://example.com/product/?x=drapes-equipment-covers&y=72586-00034-00
```

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions 
{
     public static Uri GetRawUrl(this HttpRequest request)
     {
         var httpContext = request.HttpContext;
 
         var requestFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();
 
         return new Uri(requestFeature.RawTarget);
     } 
}
```

Looking for the `RawUrl` before processing in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

From [HttpRequest.RawUrl Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.rawurl?view=netframework-4.7.2) :

> The raw URL is defined as the part of the URL following the domain
> information. In the URL string
> http://www.contoso.com/articles/recent.aspx, the raw URL is
> /articles/recent.aspx. The raw URL includes the query string, if
> present.

Do you want to get `product/?x=drapes-equipment-covers&y=72586-00034-00`  ?

Below is a demo you can refer to:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var httpContext = Request.HttpContext;
    var requestFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();
    var  rawURL = requestFeature.RawTarget;

    return View();
}
```

The request:
https://localhost:7001/home/index?x=drapes-equipment-covers&y=72586-00034-00

we can get "/home/index?x=drapes-equipment-covers&y=72586-00034-00"

result:
[image]

Comment: I am looking raw url before rewrite to IIS that is https://example.com/drapes-equipment-covers/72586-00034-00/ not https://localhost:7001/home/index?x=drapes-equipment-covers&y=72586-00034-00

Comment: @GaneshMitra  That's my request for  test , you can use your request.

Comment: already tested the same but not getting our response